# How to create an array of classes types?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, abstract-factory

I have a single class "Base", and a few tens of classes derived from Base. I would like to have a method that creates me the right class by an index. Like this:

```
class Base
{
};

class A : public Base
{
}

class B : public Base
{
}

class C : public Base
{
}

Type array = { A, B, C };
```

and then I could do `new array[i];`

How could this be achieved with C++(0x)? Usually I would use an the Abstract Factory Pattern. But since I have a LOT of derived classes, this would really slow down the program.

Since the derived classes will be used only once I also taught to use this:

```
Base *array = { new A, new B, new C };
```

But this would lead to huge memory consumption, not counting that not every class will always be used.

Any suggestion?

Comment: " since I have a LOT of derived classes, this would really slow down the program."  Have you **proved** this?  Because I highly doubt it.

Comment: What does this mean? `Type array = { A, B, C };`.

Comment: @JohnDibling: have never been too famous for their speed. When I have a switch with too many cases, I prefer to use an array of functions...

Comment: @Pubby: it's obviously wrong. It was just an example of what I would like to do... An array of class types.

Comment: Wait, so you want `new array[0]` to create an `A` nad `new array[1]` to create a `B`?

Comment: @AlfaOmega08:  I mean proved it by profiling your code in Release.  Abstract base classes do not noticeably slow a program down in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: lets see... you want a mechanism which with create ?singleton? instance of a certain derived class only on being invoked for that class...

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/184403813 -- Alexandrecu's `Typelist`s if you really want to contain classes and make new classes out of them.

Comment: You can't put classes in an array, but you can put in functors (factories, if you will) in an array.  But why do you want to index classes by integers?  If the indices mean anything, you should probably be using templates, not hundreds of derived classes.

Comment: Wish c++ had this ability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use an array of classes, but you can use an array of pointers to functions.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> (*Creator)();

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Base> make() { return new T{}; }

Creator const array[] = { make<A>, make<B>, make<C> };

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b = array[1]();

    b->foo();
}
```

For those worried by the cost of creating so many template functions, here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Base { virtual void foo() const = 0; };

struct A: Base { void foo() const { printf("A"); } };
struct B: Base { void foo() const { printf("B"); } };
struct C: Base { void foo() const { printf("C"); } };


typedef Base* (*Creator)();

template <typename T>
static Base* make() { return new T{}; }

static Creator const array[] = { make<A>, make<B>, make<C> };

Base* select_array(int i) {
    return array[i]();
}

Base* select_switch(int i) {
    switch(i) {
    case 0: return make<A>();
    case 1: return make<B>();
    case 2: return make<C>();
    default: return 0;
    }
}
```

LLVM/Clang generates the following output:

```
define %struct.Base* @select_array(int)(i32 %i) uwtable {
  %1 = sext i32 %i to i64
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x %struct.Base* ()*]* @array, i64 0, i64 %1
  %3 = load %struct.Base* ()** %2, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %4 = tail call %struct.Base* %3()
  ret %struct.Base* %4
}

define noalias %struct.Base* @select_switch(int)(i32 %i) uwtable {
  switch i32 %i, label %13 [
    i32 0, label %1
    i32 1, label %5
    i32 2, label %9
  ]

; <label>:1                                       ; preds = %0
  %2 = tail call noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned long)(i64 8)
  %3 = bitcast i8* %2 to i32 (...)***
  store i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8*]* @vtable for A, i64 0, i64 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 (...)*** %3, align 8
  %4 = bitcast i8* %2 to %struct.Base*
  br label %13

; <label>:5                                       ; preds = %0
  %6 = tail call noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned long)(i64 8)
  %7 = bitcast i8* %6 to i32 (...)***
  store i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8*]* @vtable for B, i64 0, i64 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 (...)*** %7, align 8
  %8 = bitcast i8* %6 to %struct.Base*
  br label %13

; <label>:9                                       ; preds = %0
  %10 = tail call noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned long)(i64 8)
  %11 = bitcast i8* %10 to i32 (...)***
  store i32 (...)** bitcast (i8** getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8*]* @vtable for C, i64 0, i64 2) to i32 (...)**), i32 (...)*** %11, align 8
  %12 = bitcast i8* %10 to %struct.Base*
  br label %13

; <label>:13                                      ; preds = %9, %5, %1, %0
  %.0 = phi %struct.Base* [ %12, %9 ], [ %8, %5 ], [ %4, %1 ], [ null, %0 ]
  ret %struct.Base* %.0
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not quite intelligent enough to automatically inline the functions with a regular array code (known issue with the LLVM optimizer, I don't know if gcc does better)... but using `switch` it is indeed possible.

Comment: Well, this surely works, but it will instantiate a lot of functions make<A>, make<B>, etc... Isn't there any preprocessor trick that will work? :)

Comment: @AlfaOmega08: no preprocessor trick will work, sorry. As for generating different functions... yes it will, it is ineluctable since each class has its own constructor to call. I expanded the answer with a use of `switch` to help the compiler performing the necessary inlining; it should remove the code for the functions (no longer used) and the overhead of the function call.

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef Base* BaseMaker();

template <class X> Base* make() {
  return new X;
}

BaseMaker* makers[] = { make<A>, make<B>, make<C> };

Base* b = makers[2]();
```

Comment: You are a genius guy!